# Printing mixed list in python

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.6. I am using Learn Python the hard way as reference.

I have a mixed list and I am trying to print the elements. The books says to use

format code "r" since we don't know what's in the list. But I am getting error with this.

Was this working in previous versions?  How can I print mixed list, each element a time.

Here is my code and error:

```
change = [1,'pennies',2,'dimes',3,'quarters']
for i in change:
print("I got {:r}".format(i))
```

Error Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 2, in <module>
    print("I got {:r}".format(i))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'r' for object of type 'int'
```

Thanks

Comment: It should be `!r`, not `:r`.

Answer (score 1):

For `str.format`, the "force to `repr`" conversion is done with `!r`. not `:r`; it's not asserting a type for conversion, it's saying "don't use `__format__` at all, use `__repr__` to perform the conversion". Make it:

```
print("I got {!r}".format(i))
```

Comment: The plain format specifier `{}` will handle just about anything. For example `print( '{}'.format([1,'eggs',{'spam':99}] ))` produces `[1, 'eggs', {'spam': 99}]`

Comment: @nigel222: Yar. It falls back to `str` if the object doesn't support more advanced formatting, and usually `str` is as safe as `repr` (sometimes it's the same thing). I mostly use `repr` to get a better idea of what I'm working with (since `str` is more likely to omit information about _what_ I'm working with), but they're both usually safe.